# Create variable 'order' accounting for product ID

Tags: r, excel, sorting, variables

I need to create a new variable in my dataset that accounts for posting order of online reviews.

The dataset consists of online reviews from Amazon for specific products (identified by their ASIN number) and also the corresponding Unix Time Stamp is available. So far I've been able to sort products by ASIN and, within this, by the time stamp. Now I want to create a column with posting order like this:

[I need the posting order to start from 1 every time that ASIN changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAFhv.png)

Any ideas on how to do this in Excel or R??

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `R`, we can use `ave` from `base R` to create a sequence by group ("ASIN").

```
df1$PostingOrder <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(ASIN), ASIN, FUN= seq_along))
```

A shorter, compact option would be

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(df1, "ASIN")[]
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, as your sheet is laid out, in Column E use the following formula (and fill down).

```
=IF(B2<>B1,1,E1+1)
```

Comment: Thank you OldUgly!! I modified a little bit your formula since the first row (E2) has to be 1 by default, and then `=IF(B3<>B2,1,E2+1)` was placed in E3 (and filled down). This worked out perfectly. Thanks a lot!!